# How to work with Generic type members in extension method?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, extension-methods

I started this extension method for fun, but now I find myself stuck into it,

Actually I want to create an extension method to extend LINQ, the method will look like this:

```
books.In(b => b.Id, 1,2,3,4,5);
```

It will return books with Id range in the second `params[]` ,

It also could be done like this:

```
books.In(b => b.Title, "t1","t2","t3","t4","t5");
```

What I come up with is this method (I just knew about expression tree today!):

```
 public static List<TEntity> In<TEntity, TMember>(this List<TEntity> list,
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TMember>> identifier, params TMember[] keys)
        {
            Type t = typeof(TEntity); //How to use reflection here?

            List<TEntity> myList = list.Where(m => keys.Contains(m.));
            return myList;
        }
```

my problem is how to access the generic class members: i.e. `m.Id` or `m.Title` from the `identifier` expression?
Can I use reflection to make this happen?

Comment: `identifier` should be a `Func<TEntity, TMember>` if you want to use `Enumerable.Where` to filter. Then it's just `list.Where(m => keys.Contains(identifier(m))` although you might want to create a set for the keys to make the lookup more efficient.

Comment: If the intent is for this to be translated into SQL then you should be using `IQueryable` instead of `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEnitity> In<TEnitity, TMember>(
    this IEnumerable<TEnitity> source, 
    Func<TEnitity, TMember> projector, IEnumerable<TMember> validCases)
{
    var validSet = new HashSet<TMember>(validCases);
    return source.Where(s => validSet.Contains(projector(s)));
}
```

Or, to comply exaclty with the signature you are proposing:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEntity> In<TEntity, TMember>(
    this IEnumerable<TEntity> source,
    Func<TEntity, TMember> projector, params TMember[] validCases)
{
    var validSet = new HashSet<TMember>(validCases);
    return source.Where(s => validSet.Contains(projector(s)));
}
```

On why I'm returning `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>` the reasoning is cheap generalization; if the consumer wants a list returned, then he simply needs to call `ToList`, but why make him pay the expense of enumerating greedily if maybe he only wants to iterate once through the enumeration? Remeber, LINQ is *lazy*, leverage that and make it work as little as possible.

On why I'm accepting `IEnumerable<T>` as an argument, again cheap generalization; why accept only a list? Why not an array, a queue, a stack, a collection, an iterator block, a hashset, etc?

Comment: Since this is an answer, could you please explain your code, why `IEnumerable` better than `List`

Comment: @MohamedAhmed Because `Where` just returns `IEnumerable<T>`, not `List<T>`. Furthermore: do you really want to return a list where you can add/remove items?

Comment: I have a problem with this collection family, I see them all similar :\

Comment: 1) Use more line breaks...horizontal scrolling...:S 2) you're iterating over an arbitrary `IEnumerable` (`validCases`) multiple times.  This is dangerous, in that it may not yield the same values on each iteration, may cause side effects, etc.  It's also just slow to do a linear search over and over.  Put it into a more quickly searched collection. 3) The OP appears to be trying to create methods for EF, not in memory collections, and if that's the case, none of this will work correctly.

Comment: @Servy 1) Done. 2) *could* is the key word here. The OP is talking about using `params` so I dont really see a mutating enumeration as an issue here. Same goes with performance, `params` implies a small set of members, I don't think newing up a `HashSet<TMember>` or similar is really worth it in this scenario. On top of that the answer was not meant to be performant, it was just meant to illustrate a possible solution. 3) Curious as to know why, not really up to date on EF. How could this go wrong barring what has already been said about `validCases`.

Comment: Creating a method that *sometimes* works and *sometimes* breaks is often much worse than a method that simply never works in the first place.  You try it out in a few simple cases, and it works great, then you try it in real data, or start using it in more complex situations (like, say, with EF data, rather than just simple in-memory arrays) and all of a sudden bad things start happening and you have no idea why, and don't look at code like this because you tested it and it appeared to work.

Comment: As far as performance, if the list is fixed and *very* small, then the code will be fast regardless; you only care when it's not small, so that's the case to optimize for.  If you pass in an EF query to this method the operation gets performed in memory, rather than in the database, as do any subsequent operations, which will end up consuming a *lot* of system memory, time, and CPU resources over performing the operation on the database.  Pulling an entire table into memory and *then* filtering it, rather than creating SQL to pull the few records you actually need is a *big* problem.